Prove a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism - by identifying only hyperbolic points?

Prove that the map $f(x)=x^3+\frac34x$ is a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism
on the interval $J=[-\frac12,\frac12]$.

We prove that the map $f$ is a diffeomorphism:
with \begin{equation}
    f^{-1}= \frac{1}{ 2 \big(\sqrt{1 + 16 x^2}-4x\big)^{1/3}} -  \frac12\big(\sqrt{1 + 16 x^2}-4x\big)^{1/3} 
\end{equation}

f is one to one.
f is continuous, since for $|x_1-x_0|>\epsilon$ $\exists$ $|f(x_1)-f(x_0)|>\delta$.
$f^{-1}$ is continuous also.
$f^{-1}$ is infinitely differentiable.

Then we need to prove that it is a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism.
Definition 1:
(Morse-Smale map)
A Morse-Smale map is a map which has only hyperbolic points.
Definition 2:
A hyperbolic equilibrium point $p$ is a fixed point, or equilibrium point, of $f$, such that $(Df)_p$ has no eigenvalue with absolute value $1$. In this case, $\Lambda = {p}$.
So we identify the stationary point , and then get the fixed point out of that.
\begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
 & f(x)=x^3+\frac34x\\
 & f'(x)= 3x^2 +\frac34    \\
 & f'(x)=0\implies x_{0_1}=\frac{i}{2}, x_{0_2}=-\frac{i}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We now find the fixed point of $f$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &f\bigg(\frac{i}{2}\bigg)=\frac{i}{4}\\
    &f\bigg(-\frac{i}{2}\bigg)= -\frac{i}{4}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
My question is, how can I find $(Df)_p$, such that it has no eigenvalue with absolute value $1$?
Would it be the matrix:
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{i}{4} & 0\\
0 & -\frac{i}{4}
\end{vmatrix}
has eigenvalues $\pm\frac{i}{4}\implies$ $|\frac{i}{4}|=\frac14$ . Since $\frac14\ne1$ and $\frac14\in J$ the condition of definition 2 is satisfied?
Thanks

The fixed points of your diffeomorphism are found by solving equation
$$f(x) = x$$
$$x^3 + \dfrac{3}{4}x = x \implies x_0 = 0, x_1 = 0.5, x_2 = -0.5.$$
In case of 1-dimensional maps you do not need any matricies (if you do not consider a number as $1\times 1$ matrix). Just check, that the absolute value of the derivative $|f'(x)|$ at each fixed point is not equal $1$ (if you like $1\times 1$ matrices, it is exactly its eigenvalue, and the matrix itself is diagonal).
So, $$f'(x_0) = \dfrac{3}{4} < 1,\ f'(x_1) = f'(x_2) = \dfrac{3}{2} >1.$$
Moreover you must check, that there is no other periodic points (otherwise, you must check that they are hyperbolic). It is easy to see, since
$$f(x) > x,\quad \text{if } 0 < x < 0.5$$
$$f(x) < x,\quad \text{if } -0.5 < x < 0.$$
